# VS - Managing References Across Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, csproj

My problem is that I have a Visual Studio (2010) C# solution with multiple projects and trying to manage the library for each one is nightmare. Each one of those project contains some standard library references (all pre-built).

For example:

```
Class Lib Project 1: A.dll, B.dll, C.dll
Class Lib Project 2: A.dll, B.dll, D.dll
```

So in this case, I have A.dll and B.dll beign references from a particular share drive. However, each new build of A.dll and B.dll goes into a separate folder. So if I want to upgrade to the latest library builds of A.dll and B.dll, I have to go through and change references in both projects to the new location.

Now if it was just 2 projects, no big deal. But if it's let's say 10+, then it becomes problematic, time-consuming, and error prone. Because this is a company wide process, I can't create like a directory link for a static location where latest library build would be copied to (and sometimes I don't want to automatically upgrade).

Does anyone know of a way where I can somehow centralize library references across projects under the same solution (I don't need it across solutions)?

Comment: [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) works pretty nicely for this..

Comment: We fought against this years ago (TFS2005 was just out, brand new), and decided to dump TFS and go to SubVersion for source control.  We gained the flexibility to organize the projects in a way that made it a lot easier, but we lost all of the powerful integrated project management. I miss that part a LOT.  I wish you luck, and hope you have better luck than we did.  If you do go with a suggestion from here, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, and leave a comment about how it works for you.  I'd like to give TFS another go if that problem is solved now.

Comment: others have provided additional information below but adding references to unversioned files on a share never works. Versioning the .dll files in a separate directory is the correct solution. for a central project that relies on a number of other .dll projects in the same solution add the project references to the master project and the .dll files will be included in the master project. You may also need to set build order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using source control?  Add your references (binaries) to your solution and keep them stored locally, along with the source code.

[image: References in Project]

By keeping everything together you can always go back to a particular version of the source and be able to build it, without having to worry about what binaries you were using at that time.

Also, this allows you to update the binaries once - then all the developers can just pull down the latest ones whenever they do a "get".

Edit: If you do this you also can just keep one copy of the dll which can be referenced by multiple projects in your solution.

Comment: That's in interesting solution and would work though I'm not really sure I'd want to be checking in binaries.

Comment: @Amicus - the reason you would want to check in binaries is to be able to go to any point in your source history, do a "get", and be able to do a complete build.  Otherwise you have to remember what binaries you were using at the that particular point in time.

Comment: I understood the logic. I guess I've just never heard of anyone else checking in binary libraries into source control so just seems sort of foreign to me. I'm going to mark this as the answer since this was the first suggested and doesn't require any extensions.

Comment: @Amicus - it's all about repeatability. Maybe we should refer to it as version control instead of source control :)

Answer (score 1):

When I work on complex projects (read solution with 10+ projects somehow cross dependent), normally I create in the solution root a DLL folder in which I store all the dlls used in the projects of the solution.

From each project I add the references from del these DLLs, with *copy local* option only for runnable projects (web apps, console...)

In this way if I want to upgrade A.dll I can update only in the common DLLs folder and rebuild the solution

```
- solution
 |-DLLs
 |  |- A.Dll
 |  |- B.Dll
 |  |- C.Dll
 |  |- D.Dll
 |- prj1
 |  |- References
 |  |   |- A.Dll
 |  |   |- B.Dll
 |  ...
 |- prj2
 |  |- References
 |  |   |- A.Dll
 |  |   |- B.Dll
 |  |   |- C.Dll
 |  ...
 |- prj3
 |  |- References
 |  |   |- B.Dll
 |  |   |- D.Dll
 |  ...
```

Normally the update of the libs dll (A.dll,B.dll,...) is done with a script (.bat or .ps1) so is somehow automatic but manually triggered. Anyway is possibile to trigger automatically this operation with a prebuild action

We use Nuget only for community libraries, although is possible to have a [private nuget repository](https://www.google.com/search?q=private%20nuget%20repository) it's too much for enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is the way to go.  You still have to manage them for each project (packages.config for each project) but it gives you a nice GUI to work at the solution level and it will update the projects in batch for you.  More details here: http://frozenorange.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/managing-nuget-at-the-visual-studio-solution-level/

[image: NuGet Solution Level]